# Select rows based on occurrences in another column R

Tags: r

I'm not sure if the title actually really reflects what I'm wanting to do. Ultimately I want to select rows by group that have a certain pattern in the `ActionType` column. The grouping variable is `email`. For each `email`, if the first row of `ActionType` is a win then I want to delete it and look at the second row. If the second row of `ActionType` is a win, then I want to delete it and move to the next row and so on.

Basically condition 1 is the first row for each email has to be anything but a win.

Next once that has been satisfied, I want to select everything from that first row (which is anything but a win) up to the next win.

Then the process would repeat itself until all the rows by group have been checked. I don't care about rows that occur after a win unless they precede another win. Also if two wins are back to back then I want to select the rows up to that first win (include that win). Delete the one that occurs after and then continue checking the rows and keeping those that precede another win.

I have tried using `cumsum` with `dplyr` and `data.table`, but I may have to do it in several steps.

This is how my data looks:

```
email   Action  ActionType  Date
wwww    Company won         1/17/14
wwww    Company trial       1/22/14
wwww    Event   Meeting     1/24/14
wwww    Event   Meeting     2/24/14
wwww    Gmail   Email       9/10/14
wwww    Company won         9/11/14
wwww    Company won         9/25/14
wwww    Event   Support     10/7/14
wwww    Company won         10/22/14
wwww    Company won         12/31/14
wwww    Gmail   Email       2/13/15
wwww    Gmail   Email       2/27/15
wwww    Gmail   Email       3/6/15
wwww    Gmail   Email       3/26/15
wwww    Gmail   Email       4/20/15
wwww    Gmail   Email       4/24/15
wwww    Gmail   Email       5/13/15
xxxx    Company trial       1/17/14
xxxx    Gmail   Email       1/22/14
xxxx    Event   Meeting     1/24/14
xxxx    Company won         2/24/14
xxxx    Gmail   Email       9/10/14
xxxx    Gmail   Email       9/11/14
xxxx    Gmail   Email       9/25/14
xxxx    Gmail   Email       10/7/14
xxxx    Gmail   Email       10/22/14
yyyy    Company won         1/24/14
yyyy    Company trial       2/24/14
yyyy    Task    Call        9/10/14
yyyy    Task    Call        9/11/14
yyyy    Task    Call        9/25/14
yyyy    Company won         10/7/14
yyyy    Gmail   Email       10/22/14
yyyy    Gmail   Email       12/31/14
zzzz    Company won         9/11/14
zzzz    Company won         9/25/14
zzzz    Task    Call        10/7/14
zzzz    Task    Call        10/22/14
zzzz    Company trial       12/31/14
zzzz    Gmail   Email       2/13/15
zzzz    Company won         2/27/15
zzzz    Gmail   Email       3/6/15
zzzz    Gmail   Email       3/26/15
```

So I'd like the end result to look like this.

```
email   Action  ActionType  Date
wwww    Company trial       1/22/14
wwww    Event   Meeting     1/24/14
wwww    Event   Meeting     2/24/14
wwww    Gmail   Email       9/10/14
wwww    Company won         9/11/14
wwww    Event   Support     10/7/14
wwww    Company won         10/22/14
xxxx    Company trial       1/17/14
xxxx    Gmail   Email       1/22/14
xxxx    Event   Meeting     1/24/14
xxxx    Company won         2/24/14
yyyy    Company trial       2/24/14
yyyy    Task    Call        9/10/14
yyyy    Task    Call        9/11/14
yyyy    Task    Call        9/25/14
yyyy    Company won         10/7/14
zzzz    Task    Call        10/7/14
zzzz    Task    Call        10/22/14
zzzz    Company trial       12/31/14
zzzz    Gmail   Email       2/13/15
zzzz    Company won         2/27/15
```

Comment: I'm curious what your attempts with `cumsum` look like. That seems like the right tool for the job.

Comment: Why is `xxxx    Company won         2/24/14` included? And similarly `zzzz    Cirrus  won         2/27/15`...

Comment: `xxxx Company won 2/24/14` is included since there are ActionTypes that precede it that are not "wins". And the same for `zzzz Cirrus won 2/27/15` since the first two rows for that domain are "wins" and the first condition is to select by group where the first row `ActionType != 'won'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
library(data.table)

# cut off leading wins and trailing nonwins
goodi = DT[, .I[
    rev(cumsum(rev(ActionType=="won"))) > 0L &
    cumsum(ActionType!="won") > 0L
], by=email]$V1

# take the first win when there's a succession of 'em
DT[goodi, r := rleid(ActionType=="won"), by=email]
badi = DT[!is.na(r), .I[ ActionType=="won" & 1:.N > 1], by=.(email,r)]$V1
DT[, r := NULL]

DT[setdiff(goodi,badi)]
```

which gives the desired output

```
    email  Action ActionType     Date
 1:  wwww Company      trial  1/22/14
 2:  wwww   Event    Meeting  1/24/14
 3:  wwww   Event    Meeting  2/24/14
 4:  wwww   Gmail      Email  9/10/14
 5:  wwww Company        won  9/11/14
 6:  wwww   Event    Support  10/7/14
 7:  wwww Company        won 10/22/14
 8:  xxxx Company      trial  1/17/14
 9:  xxxx   Gmail      Email  1/22/14
10:  xxxx   Event    Meeting  1/24/14
11:  xxxx Company        won  2/24/14
12:  yyyy Company      trial  2/24/14
13:  yyyy    Task       Call  9/10/14
14:  yyyy    Task       Call  9/11/14
15:  yyyy    Task       Call  9/25/14
16:  yyyy Company        won  10/7/14
17:  zzzz    Task       Call  10/7/14
18:  zzzz    Task       Call 10/22/14
19:  zzzz Company      trial 12/31/14
20:  zzzz   Gmail      Email  2/13/15
21:  zzzz Company        won  2/27/15
    email  Action ActionType     Date
```